# What's the difference between a "pull request" and a "branch"?

Tags: git, github

What's the difference between a "pull request" and a "branch"?

> pull request
>   branch

Comment: *What's the difference between an addition and a number?* (analogy)

Answer (score 2):

A pull request is not a git concept. It's something that sites like github or bitbucket use to refer to changes that are being developed on a branch to be carried into another. A branch in git is a pointer to a revision.

Answer (score 2):

In a few words and adding the concept of 'Merge':

**Branch:** you take the project at a certain stage and start a new 'version' where you can make further changes or improvements. The original version can evolve, while the new version can also evolve with further changes ('commits').

This is how a branch looks like:

[image]

**Merge:** at a certain point, you may want to include all the changes that you were making... let's merge both branches then:

[image]

**Pull Request:** in some projects, you may have permission to start a new branch but not to merge this branch back into the main branch (or maybe you just want your colleagues to have a look and review before integrating). Then you start a *pull request*. It's like *"Hey guys, have a look at this... do you think we can merge those changes into this other branch?"*.

Comment: promise, that was intended to be short... Anyway, hope it helps, for further details the documentation from Atlassian is pretty clear and images are much beeter ;) https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/using-branches

Answer (score 1):

Git has a seldom-used command [git request-pull](https://www.git-scm.com/docs/git-request-pull). The request tells others where and which ref to fetch to retrieve the pending changes, so that they can apply these changes if necessary.

> Generate a request asking your upstream project to pull changes into
>   their tree.

A pull request is a variation realized by hosting services like Github and Gitlab with the help of Git refs. The format is `refs/pull/${number}/head`. A branch is also a kind of ref, in the format of `refs/heads/foo`(local branch) or `refs/remotes/origin/foo`(remote tracking branch). Gerrit, another hosting service, implements the pending changes in another form, a change with one or more patchsets in the format like `refs/changes/11/23411/1`.

We can use `git fetch origin refs/pull/98/head` or `git fetch origin master` to fetch the pull request or the branch and retrieve the pending changes from the remote repository to the local repository.

A pull request and a branch are both refs. They have different formats. They serve different purposes. A pull request is usually generated from a branch by the hosting service.

Answer (score 0):

In a nutshell, `branch` is where the real code is stored, and `pull request` allows you merge two or more branches into one.

Official definitions:

- `git-pull` - Fetch from and integrate with another repository or a local branch
- `git-branch` - List, create, or delete branches

`Branch` allows you to `divide` and manage the code, while `pull` allows you to `merge` them back together.

More detailed descriptions, along with examples, can be found here:

- git pull: https://git-scm.com/docs/user-manual.html#sharing-development
- git branch: https://git-scm.com/docs/user-manual.html#what-is-a-branch

Usually `master` is a standard branch that many other branches (such as `dev` etc.) get merged into, using the `pull` requests.